# Неправильно отображается TableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Всем привет, создаю table view, в нем ровно 5 кастомных ячеек, все разной высоты и с разным контентом. Когда запускаю приложение, появляется пустая таблица со стандартными ячейками, чтобы я ни делал.

Comment: код класса добавьте

Comment: У вас должен быть ViewController для вашего TableView, реализующий интерфейсы UITableViewDataSource и UITableViewDelegate. Иначе как вы собираетесь наполнять таблицу контентом?

Comment: вот тут простенький туториал http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

Answer (score 1):

Надо указать `dataSource` для этого `tableView`:

или **в коде**: `tableView.dataSource = self;`

или **в ИнтерфейсБилдере**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: делегаты и датасурсы выставил, все равно не помогает

Comment: какой контроллер `UITableViewController` или `UIViewController`? Данные для таблицы загружаются с сервера? Возможно, не хватает `[tableView reloadData];` после подготовки массива.